# Retrieving/setting cookie in index.php

Tags: global-variables

I'm attempting to retrieve a cookie in index.php to record the value in a global_variable. I'd like to do it this way to avoid including PHP/plugin code on every template. Currently I have;

```
$assign_to_config['global_vars']['user_location'] = $this->EE->input->cookie('user_location');
```

However this throws the error;

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in
>   /xx/xxx/xxx/index.php on line 28

Am I allowed to do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work as object isn't being initialized. You can use PHP $_COOKIE to get it.

```
$assign_to_config['global_vars']['user_location'] = $_COOKIE['user_location'];
```

Comment: Great thank you :-) Do you know if its possible to set a cookie via the index.php file too?

Comment: You can use PHP function setcookie(). See here http://in3.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php